# __tls_get_addr@@GLIBC_2.3 SIGSEGV using JNA after porting from 32-bit to 64-bit

Tags: java, c++, jboss, jna

I've got an interesting problem that's caused me to lose half of my hair over the last 24 hours and its a bit complex so I'm hoping somewhere out in the world has the patience to read through this and then will be able to help me out!

We have a Java EE application running in JBoss that uses JNA to make a call to a Native C++ library on RedHat 6.3. The C++ library we were using used to be 32-bit but has recently been ported to 64-bit. We are now in the process of updating JBoss application to run using the 64-bit JVM (RHEL JRE 1.6_43.1).

When we ported the Native library to 64-bit we used a C++ test stub to test all of the public interfaces that are used by JNA - all of these tests pass without any problems.

Now, when I try to access the 64-bit Native library using JNA I get the following error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment
# 
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000003718b32fbc, pid=4489, tid=140200254654208
#
# JRE version: 6.0_22-b22
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (20.0-b11 mixed mode linux-amd64 compresssed oops)
# Derivative: IcedTea6 1.10.6
# Distribution: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.2 (Santiago), package rhel-1.43.1.10.6.el6_2-x86_64
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libc.so.6+0x132fbc]  __tls_get_addr@@GLIBC_2.3+0x132fbc
#
# ...
```

I have traced the source of the error down to a call that is being made to a third party library that is called from within our recently ported Native library. The call to the third party library is being made with a set of values that originate from within the Native library, not values that get passed into the library.

So for SOME REASON we get the following behaviour:
 - Call Native library from C++ test stub: Success
 - Call Native library from Java via JNA: Failure (segfault)

I'm running out of ideas about what the problem could be and my lack of knowledge of both JNA and C++ is seriously holding me back (I come from a largely Java team and drew the short straw in getting this task). If anyone has any information, pointers, advice, etc. it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `__tls_*` refers to thread-local storage; that's probably your code since JNA uses `pthread_*` functions for TLS.  What version glib is the default on your system?  Is it something other that 2.3?

Comment: Can you run your native code in 64-bit outside of the Java framework?  Might be a 64-bit issue with your native bits; developers have been known to get that stuff wrong on occasion...

Comment: Thanks technomage. My system is running glib 2.12. Also, I can run the native code successfully outside of the Java framework, which is what I find so confusing. The code runs perfectly outside of Java, but segfaults when called from JNA.